# Why there cannot be induction current between plates of capacitor while discharging?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, capacitance

If a capacitor gets charged by induction through the plates, then why there is no induction current between them while discharging instead of displacement current ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction current and displacement current are similar though, but very different terms. Induction current is the  normal electric current but displacement current is the term which is only defined by Maxwells' equations. Now generally capacitors have a dielectric material between the +ve and -ve plates. When the capacitor is charged, there exists a strong electric field between the plates. Now we have dieletric material between the plates. Hence for discharging, equivalent current flow is essential between the plates for the current flow. This means that current should also pass through dielectric material. But Maxwells' equations tell us that only displacent current can flow through dielectrics. Hence while discharging a capacitor can only have displacement current between its plates.